# Ansible - install yum packages with preconfigured sudoers privileges

Tags: ansible, yum, sudoers, rhel8

The Ansible connects to my servers using a non-root user. The goal is for this non-root user to be able to install yum packages. For this, it needs sudo privileges, so I've configured the sudoers file to allow the use of yum without a password for that user.

```
test_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/yum
```

When I log in to one of the target servers with the specified user, the installation works without any issues.

```
[test-user@TESTHOST01~]$ sudo yum update
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Microsoft Tools for RedHat 8                                                                                                                                                      33 kB/s | 2.0 kB     00:00
Oracle_yum_repository                                                                                                                                                             31 kB/s | 2.0 kB     00:00
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                                                                                                                          86 kB/s | 4.5 kB     00:00
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)                                                                                                                             68 kB/s | 4.1 kB     00:00
DockerCE_8Server                                                                                                                                                                  40 kB/s | 2.0 kB     00:00
EPEL8_REPO                                                                                                                                                                        39 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:00
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

If, however, I try to install using Ansible, it fails.

Related playbook part:

```
- name: Install docker
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    name: "{{ packages }}"
    state: present
  vars:
    packages:
    - git
    - containerd.io-1.6.9-3.1.el8
    - docker-ce-cli-1:20.10.20-3.el8
    - docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.20-3.el8
    - docker-compose-plugin-2.12.0-3.el8
  become: true
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo
```

Error I got:

```
TASK [ans_rol_docker_swarm : Install docker] ***********************************
fatal: [10.5.237.14]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}
fatal: [10.5.237.10]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}
fatal: [10.5.237.15]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}
```

Related versions:

```
Run ansible --version
  ansible --version
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    ANSIBLE_CONFIG: .github/workflows/ansible/ansible.cfg
    GIT_SSH_COMMAND: ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
ansible [core 2.13.13]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/runner/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/runner/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0]
  jinja version = 3.1.3
  libyaml = True
```

```
[test-user@TESTHOST01~]$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.9 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.9"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.9 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.9
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.9"
```

Comment: To use `become` with Ansible you need to grant the ability to run *any* command using `sudo`. Ansible isn't connecting to the remote system and running `sudo yum install`; it's running a Python script using `sudo` (and that script will at some point run the `yum install` command).

Comment: There is no way to specify a short list of commands that can be executed without granting all rights to an ansible user?

Comment: Ansible isn't running individual commands using `sudo`. This is mentioned [in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general). Run ansible verbosely (`-vvv`) and you can see exactly what commands it is executing on the target system.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out and showing me the relevant documentation excerpt.
If you post it like an answer, I can accept it as result for you.